# Extract Number from String Field, Including Decimal (Postgres 9.5)

Tags: regex, postgresql

Suppose I have a field:

```
product_strength
10MG/ML
0.25MG
25MG
0.125MG
```

How do I extract just the "numeric" part and then cast to numeric? I can get this far: `regexp_replace(product_strength, '(\D|!\.)','','g')::numeric AS result_numeric`

But the problem with this is that it doesn't actually account for the decimal. In other words, this returns

```
product_strength result_numeric
10MG/ML             10
0.25MG              25
25MG                25
0.125MG             125
```

But I would want to return

```
product_strength result_numeric
10MG/ML             10
0.25MG              0.25
25MG                25
0.125MG             0.125
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [this](https://regex101.com/r/WObCzI/2) regex to match the numbers;

```
\d+\.?\d*
```

Edit: as "Boolean_Type" says, if you need negative numbers too, you could add in an optional negative sign, and use;

```
\-?\d+\.?\d*
```

Comment: My actual use case is in sqlalchemy, and I have: `sa.cast(sa.func.regexp_matches(col, '\d+\.?\d*'), sa.Numeric)`. How can I access the first element of the array returned by `sa.func.regexp_matches`? I tried `sa.cast(sa.func.regexp_matches(col, '\d+\.?\d*')[0], sa.Numeric)` but that didn't work

Comment: Ah nevermind, I was actually able to use the `substring` function. So this worked for me: `substring (product_strength, '\d+\.?\d*')::numeric` or in sqlalchemy: `sa.cast(sa.func.substring(col, '\d+\.?\d*'), sa.Numeric)`

Comment: This solution takes into account possible negative numbers: `\-?\d+\.?\d*`.

Answer (score 6):

I would use regexp_matches for this:

```
select (regexp_matches(product_strength, '[0-9]+\.?[0-9]*'))[1]::numeric
from the_table
```

regexp_matches() returns an array of all matched strings, that's why the `[1]` is needed.

Comment: This pattern matches the empty string `''`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name this doesn't match all instances of number. For example, `12a15b` => `{12}`. What I need is `{12,15}`. I've tried the `g` modifier: `(regexp_matches(product_strength, '[0-9]+\.?[0-9]*', 'g'))` but this didn't work